# How to Convert ost emails to pdf document

Tags: pdf, conversion, mailbox

I have some important professional emails with some attachments in OST Mailbox, but now I want to move OST emails to PDF format. Is there any solution to convert in PDF Format?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered printing them with a PDF printer driver?

Comment: I have multiple OST files which I want to convert in PDF format.

Comment: First approach would be to open them in Outlook, then print to a pdf converter. Probably you can also find macros for that on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for your attention but I don't want to print them. As I want to convert them and save them for future use. So please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @selah1936, it sounds like you may have never used a pdf printer driver.  It doesn't print, it converts.  You access it like it's a printer (it shows up in the printer list, you select that "printer", and print the document).  It takes the output that would have gone to a printer, and converts it to a PDF file, which it saves on your hard drive.  You can select and "print" a collection of emails.

Comment: Will it convert my attachments??

Comment: If you can print it, it can be converted to PDF.  There are a ton of free ones, so just load one and play with it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to convert the ost file to pdf.

You want to convert the contents of emails in those temporarily cached emails (.ost) to PDFs. Possibly with or without their headers.

That means using a outlook (or anything which understands ost, which as far as I know is only outlook), connecting to your exchange mail server; only then are you able to access the emails.  And once you are able to access them you can somehow process them to PDFs. The easiest way to do that is to select the emails and print them.

Multiple selections are the same time seem to work in outlook (just tested that in outlook 2013 64bit). The command to print is <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.

And PDF printers are thirteen in a dozen. I trust you will be able to find those on your own.

Comment: his e-mails have also attachments, how to print those?

Comment: You are not able to get my question. As I want to convert them. Taking print-out is not an option. I want to convert and save them for future use.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Good point about attachements.  @ OP: printing to PDF is not printing then out. It converts your output to a PDF.